# Нужен эффективный бинарный протокол для С\С++ для сериализации данных (с точки зрения объёма сериализованных данных)

Tags: c++, c, сериализация, google-protobuf

Есть задача передать фиксированный объём данных по беспроводной сети. Узким местом системы является объём трафика, скорость сериализации-десериализации второстепенна. Нужен бинарный протокол, который во время сериализаций сгенерируем самый маленький пакет. Из бинарных протоколов у меня большой опыт работы с Google protobuf, но для этой задачи он генерирует очень большие пакеты. Хотелось-бы что-то похожее на него, но что бы ему можно было задать размеры данных в битах. Например, у меня много переменных, максимальное значение которых не превысит 16ти. Протобуф будет выделять под них по 1 байту, хотя можно уложиться в 4 бита. Есть что-то эффективней протобуфа?

Условия у моей задачи следующие:

- Структура передаваемых данных известна заранее. Т.е. на этапе компиляции мы точно знаем какие пакеты будем передавать.
- Каждый тип пакета должен быть фиксированной длинны, которая выбирается на этапе компиляции. Т.е. если у нас есть 3 типа пакета, то на этапе компиляции мы должны знать максимальный размер всех трёх типов. Если у какого-то типа пакет, после сериализации, может занимать от 12 до 16 байте, то при получении 12 байт мне всё равно придётся добивать его до 16 и передавать 16 байт.
- Очень желательно (но не обязательно) чтобы библиотека была хедер-онли. Часть работы будет производиться на микроконтроллере.

***upd:*** Если немного переформулировать вопрос, то нужен протокол, который сгенерирует самый маленький бинарный пакет в наихудшем случае. В обсуждении с user7860670 я объяснил почему любой алгоритм сжатия не подходит (из-за второго ограничения). Все отдельные поля объектов были сокращены еще до сериализации (т.е. если значения, которые могут быть от 10 до 16 приводятся к 0-6 и переводятся в 3 битовый размер. Числа с плавающей запятой нормализуются и переводятся в intxx_t и т.д.). Всё что мне нужно, это эффективный бинарный протокол. Хотя @Mike в комментариях уже подсказал решение, которое меня устраивает.

Comment: А почему бы не упаковывать данные в более-менее крупные пакеты для протобуфа?

Comment: @MBo Я так и сделал. Например, у меня есть объект с 22мя полями. Но 20 из этих полей меньще 8 бит, поэтому превратил это всё в битовую маску и передаю массивом внутри protobuf объекта. Попробовал сериализовать это всё при помощи boost::dynamic_bitset, но это полный треш. Сложно кода запредельная, на каждый пакет нужно писать новый сериализатор. Выгода от применения protobuf полностью нивилируеться, он теперь больше мешает. Я выкинул протобуф и начал писать свой бинарный сериализатор, но у меня возникает жгучее чувство что я пишу велосипед.

Comment: @Rivand, вопрос  ваш  я оценил(и мне интересен ответ), но почему то мне кажется, что вы пишете даже не велосипед. Если у вас объект с 22 мя полями,  не малый повод для сомнения о правильном проектировании. Может воспользуетесь патернами проектирования (например `Builder`)?

Comment: @Rivand Велосипед рассчитанный под особенности своих данных обычно эффективнее универсальных библиотек. И кстати, чем обычная _C_ структура с битовыми полями не подходит ? Там много полей сильно переменной длины ?

Comment: ¿Тут случаем нет попытки сэкономить на спичках? ¿Сколько у вас данных передаются? ¿Какой характер у этих данных (например временные ряды или видео)?

Comment: @Mike обычная структура еще менее эффективна чем protobuf в большинстве случаев, т.к. в протобуфе используется инты переменной длинны и еще куча всяких фишек для оптимизации размера.

Comment: @user7860670 ограничения в канале примерно 200 байт в секундну. Применяется аналог Lora (но не Lora) с временным разделением. Из-за временного разделения и возникает ограничение на необходимость знать размер пакета на этапе компиляции т.е. надо точно знать сколько времени мне выделять для выхода в эфир. Уверяю вас, что экономии на спичках нет, приходиться сражаться за каждый байт.

Comment: @Mike я извиняюсь за свой предыдущий коментарий, до меня только сейчас дошло про что вы говорили. Скорее всего вы имели в виду структуры типа `struct A {uint8_t a:2; uint8_t b:3; uint8_t c:3; };` Я совсем забыл что так можно. В последний раз использовал этот трюк лет 10 назад и сейчас, прочитав ваш коментарий, вспомнил про него. Да, это сущесвенно облегчает дело.

Comment: @Rivand Ага, именно это. Еще не забудьте про всякие там `__attribute__((__packed__))` (посмотрите как там ваш компилятор это обычно задает) а то по умолчанию может быть выравнивание int на границы 2-4 байта.

Answer (score 1):

Как учит нас товарищ Шеннон, все зависит от вероятностного распределения входных данных и от их природы, без детального изучения природы каждого параметра что-то ответить сложно.

Алгоритмы сжатия, которые тут настойчиво предлагают, как раз и занимаются тем, что автоматически пытаются изучить природу входного сигнала с тем, чтобы пересылать его максимально эффективно.

Подумайте например над тем, чтобы передавать не саму величину, а дельту от предыдущего состояния.

Очевидно, что требования "длина пакета априори известна и фиксирована" и "хочу все сжать максимально" - являются противоречивыми, реализовать можно что-то одно - сжатие приводит к пакетам переменной длины.

**Предложение**

1. оценить потребные скорости (длина фрейма в байтах) и задержки (время между фреймами). Через сколько посланных фреймов данных произойдет реальное устаривание? Действительно ли пропускная способность выбранного вами канала укладывается в эти рамки? Действительно ли сюда подходит TDM? Возможно, что вы изначально посадили себя в лужу, выбрав не те технологии.
2. Подробно расписать, какой природы данные вы пересылаете. Двоичное состояние датчика, аналоговый сигнал и так далее. Если речь идет об аналоговом сигнале, нужно оценить его спектр. Если о двоичном - частоту дискретизации и вероятности появления каждого нового состояния.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. В обсуждении ответа @user7860670 я указал почему не получиться использовать сжатие. Так-же прочитав ваш ответ я добавил к посту upd в котором пояснил что всё что можно было сократить на уровне данных, я сократил. Вопрос остался только в том, как это всё сериализовать.